# Responsive grid individual item size

Tags: css, image, grid, size

Is there a way to make grid size not uniform and be based on the size of the content for each individual items instead of using the size of the largest item's size.[image: image of different size made using grid]

Comment: you need to set numbers of row or columns to span so element https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-column-row  , else you have one element for each cell f the grid . you may use column CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns  if it is only about going through rows or the masonry javascript https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, you can use `float: left` to achieve what you want. There is [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grtavares/sfL0e49z/) with the code.

```html
<div class="wrapper cf">
    <div class="item">Your content goes here</div>
    <div class="item">Your content goes here</div>
</div>
```

```css
.cf {
  *zoom: 1;

  &::after {
    clear: both;
  }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }
}

.item {
  float: left;
}
```

For the maximum with, you will need to set it with some rule, for example, using a column grid, or manually for each individual element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
grid-auto-rows: max-content;
```

Comment: Please give an example by adding that property to a CSS class and creating a skeleton HTML code where the class will be used.